# Why doesn't fill_between work here?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using Anaconda 2.7 and my `fill_between()` attempts are coming up fruitless. I'm not sure if I'm missing a package or if my plotting syntax is throwing python off...

This is my code:

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace

alpha_A = 11
beta_A = 41
alpha_B = 3
beta_B = 3

x = linspace(0,1,num = 1000)
postA = stats.beta(alpha_A, beta_A).pdf(x)
postB = stats.beta(alpha_B, beta_B).pdf(x)


plt.figure(2, figsize = (6,4))
plt.plot(postA, color = 'r', label = "A: Beta(" + str(alpha_A) + ',' + str(beta_A) + ')')
plt.plot(postB, color = 'b',label = "B: Beta(" + str(alpha_B) + ',' + str(beta_B) + ')')
plt.legend(loc = "best", frameon = False)
plt.fill_between(x, postA, facecolor = "red") # <---- not working
frame1 = plt.gca()
frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([0,200,400,600,800,1000])
ax.set_xticklabels( ['0.0','0.2','0.4','0.6','0.8','1.0']) # https://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#setting-tick-labels
ax.set_title("Posterior Distributions")
```

This gives me this graph, in which no red fill appears: [image]

Comment: You should almost never use `set_xticklabels`

Comment: How else would I get it to display the x-axis going from 0 to 1? It is a probability distribution so I want to communicate the range over which it is defined.

Comment: As the accepted answer shows, plot against the actually x-value of each point.

Comment: @tcaswell Is there a more general reason to not use `set_xticklabels`?
Or just in this case, as he should have transformed the data not the ticklabels?

Comment: @MaxNoe In general if you have quantitative tick labels you should be using the mpl has a infrastructure for formatting the tick labels. This makes sure that as you pan/zoom the labels remain correct.  The only exception is if your labels are qualitative.

Comment: But for explicitly setting the labels, e.g. for printed plots, it's the right function, not something now deprecated, right? I often set the labels manually or via functions i created. E.g. for having ticklabels like `'$\frac{1}{2}\pi$'` or use siunitx for proper spacing when using Tex and a comma as decimal separator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It actually works, if you zoom on left hand side of your plot (you can see it on the image you show, the vertical line that goes up to 7).

So, why is that ?

It's because your plot goes up to 1000 on x axis, and you ask to fill it up to 1 (max(x)).

**2 solutions :**

**The quick one :**

You replace this line :

```
plt.fill_between(x, postA, facecolor = "red")
```

by this one

```
plt.fill_between(range(len(x)), postA, facecolor = "red")
```

**The clean one** :

where the second part of your code become :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, postA, color = 'r', label = "A: Beta(" + str(alpha_A) + ',' + str(beta_A) + ')')
ax.plot(x, postB, color = 'b',label = "B: Beta(" + str(alpha_B) + ',' + str(beta_B) + ')')
ax.legend(loc = "best", frameon = False)
ax.fill_between(x, postA, facecolor = "red")
ax.set_title("Posterior Distributions")
```

Here you give the x value in your plot as being x, and not len(postA) if you give nothing else than Y value. So you'll have the right x-ticks directly.

Here the result with the clean solution :

[image: fill_between]

Hope this helps.